# Error while running Trello on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I downloaded and unzipped `Trello-linux-0.1.9.zip`. I opened a terminal and add execution permission to Trello file.

But when I try to run Trello, nothing happened. When I run Trello on a terminal, this error occurred:

> ./Trello: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

what should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command and the error solved:

```
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```